# angular 2 - ng2-bootstrap typeahead - How to NOT select any option?

Tags: angular, typeahead, ng2-bootstrap

I am using Typeahead of ng2-bootstrap and it works fine. I type and get completion suggestions - but it seems to be impossible to **not select any**.

For example:
I type "lorem ip" in a search-input field and get a suggestion for "lorem ipsum". I am not able to just submit "lorem ip". There is always a preselected option, that gets submitted on enter.

Isn't it possible to **not preselect anything!?**
Or does anyone have an idea how to **work around it?**

Here is my code:

**html**

```
<input  [(ngModel)]="query" name="query" type="text" required
        [typeaheadOptionField]="'value'"
        [typeahead]="autocomplete()"
        [typeaheadMinLength]="3"
        (typeaheadOnSelect)="autocompleteOnSelect($event)"/>
```

**typescript**

```
autocomplete(): Observable<SearchAutocompleteSuggest[]> {
    return this.documentService.autocomplete(this.searchRequest);
}

public autocompleteOnSelect(e:any):void {
    this.search();
}
```

Comment: I just noticed, that by pressing ESC the typeahead closes. But this should not be required. In my case autocomplete/typeahead should only be a suggestion, not a default option.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input  [(ngModel)]="query" name="query" type="text" required
    [typeaheadOptionField]="'value'"
    [typeahead]="autocomplete()"
    [typeaheadMinLength]="3"
    (typeaheadOnSelect)="autocompleteOnSelect($event)"
    (keyup.enter)="autocompleteOnselect($event)"/>
```

this way you will get the option just by pressing enter and you don't have to choose one of suggestions. however you will need to make sure only one of the two events `typeaheadOnSelect` and `keyup.enter` will end up calling the method autocompleteOnselect(), to do that you can use a lock or mutex although i'm not sure if it's the best practice or not.